# changing fluorescent multi ballast lights with 7 wires and wall switch to simple led 3 wire lamp

Tags: circuit-breaker

i have situation where one end of old multi ballast lights have on one end a green (grond} a hot all the time red then a black and white wire. on other end there are black,white, and ground, that have no power switch on or off

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you include more info, especially a picture of the ballast connections? And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the fixture and the switch box?